# Oracle Query for formatting my result

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Actually i have a table in my database with name Employee.
The table consists of 5 columns ENO,ENAME,ESAL,EEMAIL,EMOBILE.
When i execute a SELECT query the result is as follows.

```
ENO    ENAME   ESAL   EEMAIL
-----  ----- ------- --------
EMOBILE
---------
123   ram    10000    x@y.com
98480
```

but i need my result as follows,(all column headers in one row)

```
ENO   ENAME   ESAL   EEMAIL   EMOBILE
---- ------  ------ -------- ---------
123  ram      10000  x@y.com  98480
```

Any help would be appreciated....Thanqq...:)

Comment: the question isn't posted properly.....:(
my query is to get all the table headers in a single roww...

Comment: Do you mean something like `set linesize n` where `n` is line width ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use concatenation operator

```
 select 
 CONCAT(ENO ,
    CONCAT( ENAME, 
      CONCAT(ESAL, 
        CONCAT(EEMAIL, EMOBILE))))  
 from Employee
```

or use ||

```
    select ENO || ENAME || ESAL || EEMAIL || EMOBILE  from Employee
```

Comment: then can use alias (AS) command to the change the header of column.